# Supervisor Strategy: Compile error - Resume/Restart/Stop/Escalate incompatible with Directive

Tags: java, compiler-errors, akka

it's my first time trying akka - and I'm so stuck.
I found some [tutorial code on the official akka website](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.5/java/fault-tolerance.html)  which sets up a supervisor strategy but I keep getting the following 4 compilation errors:

> Incompatible types.
>
> Required: akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.Directive
>
> Found:    akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.Resume   <--same for Restart, Stop, Escalate

My gut feeling tells me that I got something really basic wrong, below are the libriaries I used and a minimum failing example.

Cheers, Seb

libraries: scala-library:2.11.2, akka-actor_2.11:2.3.5, jdk 1.7.0_45

```
import akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy;
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import akka.japi.Function;
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;

import static akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.*;

class MyWorker extends UntypedActor {

    private static SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy =
            new OneForOneStrategy(10, Duration.create("1 minute"),
                    new Function<Throwable, Directive>() {
                        @Override
                        public Directive apply(Throwable t) {
                            if (t instanceof ArithmeticException) {
                                return SupervisorStrategy.resume();
                            } else if (t instanceof NullPointerException) {
                                return restart();
                            } else if (t instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
                                return stop();
                            } else {
                                return escalate();
                            }
                        }
                    });


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was two issues:

a) turned out that IntelliJ IDEA 12 had seems to have had problems with Scala. Version 13.1 works like a charm out of the box.

b) maven stopped complaining about a missing SupervisorStrategy$1.class after I made the static imports explicit (e.g. import static akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.resume).